# How to tell when it's hypergeometric?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have this question where they ask to find the expected value of payoffs through the probability of getting 0,1 and 2 red balls from 2 drawings out of a stereotypical bag filled with 4 whites and 2 red without replacement. I thought I could find the probability of 0 red balls to be $\frac{4\cdot3}{6\cdot5}$ etc but the answer said it was a hypergeometric random variable thus solved it using the r code: prob = dhyper( 0:2, 2, 4, 2 ). Can someone explain why my method doesn't work and when to use a hypergeom?

Thanks

Comment: You are dealing with hypergeometric distribution because there is no replacement. BTW that does not mean that your way of finding the probability on 0 red balls does not work. It is okay.

Answer (score 1):

You did $\dfrac{4\cdot3}{6\cdot5} =0.4$ for the probability of $0$ red, and you could also do $\dfrac{4\cdot2}{6\cdot5} +\dfrac{2\cdot4}{6\cdot5} \approx 0.5333$ for the probability of $1$ red,
and  $\dfrac{2\cdot1}{6\cdot5} \approx 0.0667$ for the probability of $2$ red

This is a hypergeometric distribution giving $\dfrac{{2\choose r}{4\choose 2-r}}{6 \choose 2}$  for the probability of $r$ red in $2$ draws.

In R you would get the same answers:

```
dhyper( 0:2, 2, 4, 2 )
# 0.40000000 0.53333333 0.06666667
```

Comment: Another computation in R would use the binomial coefficients in the formula toward the end: In R, the code `choose(2,0)*choose(4,2)/choose(6,2)` returns
$0.4.$